# Is possível two heterogenous databases as a only one transactional

Tags: teiid

My scenario has two different versions of the same system with different database structures, where 1.0 is in production and 2.0 in dev.

Version 2.0 needs to go into production using the data and structure of version 1.0 for a specified time. Our team would like not to change the data structure of 2.0, the question is whether through a VDB it would be possible for 2.0 to manipulate the base 1.0 by performing queries and transactions.

Our knowledge of teiid is still quite initial, so we would like advice if teiid would be a possibility for our need, if it would be a way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a vdb to provide a stable interface to a single or set of sources.  As long as the sources support XA, you can perform transactionally safe reads/writes across them.